# whatever happened to the conference International Symposium on Voronoi Diagrams in Science and Engineering (ISVD)?

Tags: computational-geometry

I am not sure of a better place to ask this, hopefully someone here knows something...

I've been "away" from computational geometry topics for a bit and thought I'd catch up in some way by checking out the latest proceedings of the ISVD conference. Unfortunately it seems to have disappeared a few years ago and never returned!?!? Did it get merged with another conference? Or has it just been abandoned?

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://voronoi.hanyang.ac.kr/isvd2014/) is what I could find:

---

[image: ISVD]

[image: Postponed]
${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$